# Cumulative occurrence count

Tags: python, list, count

I have a number of lists that have 2 dimensions and I need to get 
**cumulative count elements**:

```
a=[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4]
b=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4]
c=[1,2,2,2,3,4]
c=[] 
for i in a:
    for x,y in enumerate(c):
       print i
       if y[0]==i:
           y[1]+=1
       else:
           c.append([i,1])
```

I need to obtain:

```
[[1,9],[2,10],[3,7]...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

a=[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4]
b=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4]
c=[1,2,2,2,3,4]

res = Counter()
for x in (a, b, c):
    res.update(x)

print res # Counter({2: 10, 1: 9, 3: 8, 4: 5})
```

If you need the result as `list` instead of `dict` you can then sort it to a list:

```
print sorted(res.iteritems()) # [(1, 9), (2, 10), (3, 8), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: Ok, i think about it but i have to use it as list to make operation on it

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, only for Python 3.5+:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([*a, *b, *c])
Counter({2: 10, 1: 9, 3: 8, 4: 5})
```

If you really need the list of lists format, the conversion goes like this:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in Counter([*a, *b, *c]).items()]
[[1, 9], [2, 10], [3, 8], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use counter and itertools:

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools

a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
b = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
c = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]

# this will iterate through the 3 lists in sequence, and count the number of occurrences of each element
res = Counter(itertools.chain(a, b, c))

[[key, value] for key, value in res.items()]
```

### Result:

```
[[1, 9], [2, 10], [3, 8], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do it.

```
from operator import add
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter
reduce(add, (Counter(l) for l in (a,b,c)))
# Counter({1: 9, 2: 10, 3: 8, 4: 5})
```

---

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for l in (a,b,c):
    for i in l:
        d[i] += 1
# defaultdict(int, {1: 9, 2: 10, 3: 8, 4: 5})
```